# HAProxy ACL Map with Domain to Backend Map

Tags: haproxy

This is my current frontend config. How would I go about including ACLs based on src IP with certain backends. Example I would only want to allow 10.10.0.0 and 10.5.0.0 to web hosts (linux and windows) but allow 0.0.0.0/0 (all) to public hosts.

```
frontend web
  bind :80
  bind :443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/[redacted]/
  http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc }
  option http-server-close
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  use_backend %[req.hdr(host),lower,map_dom(/etc/haproxy/maps/hosts.map)]
```

Example /etc/haproxy/maps/hosts.map

```
example1.com webhost-linux-servers
example2.com webhost-windows-servers
example3.com publichost-linux-servers
example4.com publichost-windows-servers
```